# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

В чем может быть проблема? Кнопка реализована как MaterialButton. Все нужные библиотеки и стили подключены.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/Find"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:onClick="Find"/>
```

gradle

```
 compile group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha05'


    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'design', version: '28.0.0'

    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: '28.0.0'
```

Стили

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
        <item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_right</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_top</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator" tools:ignore="NewApi">@animator/mtrl_btn_state_list_anim</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">@null</item>
        <item name="elevation">@dimen/mtrl_btn_elevation</item>
        <item name="iconPadding">@dimen/mtrl_btn_icon_padding</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_ripple_color</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearance">?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent</item>
    </style>
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_right</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/mtrl_btn_stroke_color_selector</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">@dimen/mtrl_btn_stroke_size</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 7):

Проверьте, наследуется ли основная тема вашего приложения от `Theme.MaterialComponents`, и если нет то попробуйте унаследоваться.

Comment: Да, спасибо. В этом и была проблема